# Monochrome Bitmap C++ GDIPlus

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gdi+

I'm currently having issues displaying a monochrome bitmap to my form. I belive that somehow I am setting up my bitmap incorrectly, but I can't see where that would be at the moment. All I have to do to "fix" this issue is set the biBitCount to 24, but then when I call DWORD d = GetCharacterPlacementA latter on I'm seeing corrupted memory latter on. So I'm trying to keep my original desire for a monochrome bitmap and not leak memory.

Currently I'm storing my bitmap information in the standard variables:

```
BITMAPINFO bi24BitInfo;
HDC hMemoryDC;
HBITMAP hMemoryBitmap;
HGDIOBJ hDefaultBitmap;
HBITMAP hGdiBitmap;
```

This is how I am setting up the bitmap:

```
hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader);   // size of this struct
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 600;//sizeRect.cx;      // width of window
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 600;//sizeRect.cy; // height of window
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 1;               // monochrome // rgb 8 bytes for each component(3)
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;   // Means its uncompressed. Has nothing to do with color.
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = pelsPerMeter;
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = pelsPerMeter;
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 2;
bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue = 0;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbRed = 0;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbGreen = 0;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbReserved = 0;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[1].rgbBlue = (BYTE)0xFF;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[1].rgbRed = (BYTE)0xFF;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[1].rgbGreen = (BYTE)0xFF;
bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[1].rgbReserved = 0;

// Create the memory bitmap
if (hMemoryBitmap != NULL)
{
    DeleteObject(hMemoryBitmap);
}
hMemoryBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hMemoryDC, 600, 600);
hDefaultBitmap = SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hMemoryBitmap);
HGDIOBJ hOldFont = SelectObject(hMemoryDC, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
// Do not fill background
int nOldBkMode = GetBkMode(hMemoryDC);
SetBkMode(hMemoryDC, TRANSPARENT);

int nRet(0);

if (hDIB != NULL)
{
    GlobalFree(hDIB);
}
DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth * bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;
//DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth * bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight)/8);
// Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that call HeapAlloc using a handle
// to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
DWORD D = GetLastError();
pBytes = (BYTE*)GlobalLock(hDIB);
D = GetLastError();
nRet = GetDIBits(hMemoryDC, hMemoryBitmap, 0, (UINT)bi24BitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, pBytes, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi24BitInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
D = GetLastError();
if (pBitmap != NULL)
{
    delete pBitmap;
    pBitmap = NULL;
}
pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(&bi24BitInfo, pBytes);
D = GetLastError();
GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
D = GetLastError();
```

Then after all of this I'm getting an error in the following:

```
pGraphics = Graphics::FromImage(pBitmap);
// set a graphics property
s = pGraphics->SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);
```

After this pGraphics->LastResult is now set to "OutOfMemory" and s is set to the enum "InvalidParameter" from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534175(v=VS.85).aspx

Any help on this would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

`BITMAPINFO` only contains room for one palette entry; when you write to `bi24BitInfo.bmiColors[1]` you're clobbering the memory that follows, likely the `hMemoryDC`. Fix this by creating another structure that contains `BITMAPINFO` at the front and an array for the palette following.

**Edit:** It appears you aren't able to create a Graphics object from a monochrome bitmap. From the [`Graphics::FromImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535696(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> This method also fails if the image
>   has one of the following pixel
>   formats:
>
> - PixelFormatUndefined
> - PixelFormatDontCare
> - **PixelFormat1bppIndexed**
> - PixelFormat4bppIndexed
> - PixelFormat8bppIndexed
> - PixelFormat16bppGrayScale
> - PixelFormat16bppARGB1555

Comment: Interesting. Odd that they didn't make it a pointer. I guess I'll just need to make my own structure. Not a big deal. I'll see if this works.

Comment: @Alikar, I don't see anywhere that you are creating `hMemoryDC`. I hope that's just an oversight?

Comment: That actually gets created in the initialization function I use. hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL); However, I'll add it to the code above to be clear.

Comment: Yah I saw that too ealier to this week. Was rather dissapointed when I saw this in the documentation. Thanks for the help though!